# saving the bounding box image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

Instead of trying to draw the bounding box over the image, i am trying to save it as a new image.

When i was getting [ymin, xmax, ymax, xmin] points, i was doing this.

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('ballet_106_0.jpg')
image = np.array(image)

boxes = [21, 511, 41, 420 ]
ymin, xmax , ymax ,xmin = boxes

im2 = image[ymin:ymax,xmin:xmax,:]
cv2.imwrite('bboximage.jpg',im2)
```

But if i only get the `x` and `y` points along with the `height` and `width`. I'm not sure how i could index the numpy array.

Any suggestions would be really helpful ,Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks ok, though this line:

```
image = np.array(image)
```

is not required, as if everything goes well `cv2.imread` produce `np.array`, however if `cv2.imread` fails it returns `None`, which might be source of your problem, please add following line below your `cv2.imread`:

```
print(type(image))
```

if it prints `None`, it most probably means that there is not `ballet_106_0.jpg` image in your directory.

EDIT: To convert `x,y,height,width` to `x/y-min/max` values simply do

```
ymin = y
ymax = y+height
xmin = x
xmax = x+width
```

Comment: I think i failed to communicate my question clearly , The piece of code i have attached was when i was getting a list of points which were the [ymin, xmax , ymax ,xmin]. But now instead given points [ x, y ,width , height] how do i index my array to given be the bouding box image.

Comment: This is Amazing ,Thanks a lot